# Granting Capabilities to a user through PAM doesn't apply to SSH

Tags: pam, capabilities

I am using CentOS 8, and I would like to grant a user the `cap_dac_read_search` capability though PAM. It seems to work through local login and `su`, but not through `ssh`.

I followed these steps, and only them:

1. created the file `/etc/security/capability.conf`, and wrote inside:

   ```
   cap_dac_read_search user1
   ```
2. edited `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

   ```
   #%PAM-1.0
   auth       required     pam_cap.so
   auth       substack     password-auth
   auth       include      postlogin
   ...
   ```
3. Restarted the SSH service:

   ```
   systemctl restart sshd
   ```

However, when I log in with `user1` through `ssh`, and use the `capsh` command I can see:

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ capsh --print
Current: =
```

When I am doing a similar thing with `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/su`, everything seems to be in order.

I made sure, and checked the `sshd` config, and `UsePam` is set to `true`.

### Update:

I get the following error in `audit.log`, I think SELinux is blocking me for some reason:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1621457365.510:253): avc: denied { setcap } for pid=1969 comm="sshd" scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclas s=process permissive=0
```

Comment: On Debian there is a definition for `auth optional pam_cap.so` already in the `common-auth` include file, which is referenced by `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Adding a capability to `/etc/security/capability.conf` just worked as expected (no need even to restart the `sshd` service)

Comment: @roaima libpam-cap has still to be installed (else there's only the man page).

Comment: @A.B yes. my earlier comment said I'd installed that, but I then changed it. Do you think it's worth mentioning it in an answer? It seems they probably already have it though. I don't have CentOS so I don't know the default state of affairs with `pam_cap` on that platform.

Comment: The thing that appears worth mentioning is that this works even with ssh keys (from testing both).

Comment: I'd really need a CentOS 8 box to be sure of answering this accurately. It's part of a subsystem that's subtly different on different distributions.

Comment: I see the same issue on CentOS 7

Comment: @roaima installing an lxc container is often enough to test this. Except that capabilities might sometimes be more restricted and require (lxc) configuration changes.

Comment: works in a centos8-within-lxc-over-debian-bullseye. Si I'd probably need a VM to get it to fail

Comment: not SELinux denied logs? Just in case...

Comment: @A.B I checked /var/log/audit/audit.log, I don't see anything relevant

Comment: I did not install any package,  perhaps this is the issue? the packages libcap.x86_64 and
libcap-ng.x86_64 have been preinstalled.

Comment: For debugging, if it works with plain login but not ssh, you could check with inotifywait if an ssh login triggers the reading of /etc/security/capability.conf or not.

Comment: I tried the same on Ubuntu, and I had the same issue until I installed libpam-cap.
I can't find a similar package for CentOS

Comment: You don't have to find it. `/usr/lib64/security/pam_cap.so`is already provided by libcap-2.26-4.el8.x86_64

Comment: I get the following error in audit.log, I think SELinux is blocking me for some reason:
type=AVC msg=audit(1621457365.510:253): avc:  denied  { setcap } for  pid=1969 comm="sshd" 
scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclas s=process permissive=0

Comment: @ben That's why I asked about SELinux: try `setenforce Permissive` see if that works. Then revert to Enforcing and figure out if there's a good reason it's blocked, and maybe try to craft an exception (audit2allow might help but sometimes it tells rubish).

Comment: @A.B. Thanks, you were right.
Setting SELinux to permissive works. Also adding an exception works in enforced mode. 
I can't find a good why it's blocked. I tried using sealert and it doesn't give any new info.

Comment: sealert shows: "Policy RPM selinux-policy-3.14.3-41.el8.noarch" which doesn't tell me much.

Answer (score 2):

[I'm relatively new here, so don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment. So...]

For an answer, I converted the concerns expressed here into a [feature request](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213279) for [`pam_cap.so`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/commit/?id=071efa09e906a3d6928b49778b1a28ad7c0db5be). This was implemented via the [`autoauth` module argument](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/diff/pam_cap/capability.conf?id=071efa09e906a3d6928b49778b1a28ad7c0db5be) in the [libcap-2.51 release](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/release-notes-for-libcap).

Answer (score 0):

With `sshd` you need to explicitly configure it to use PAM

```
 UsePAM  Enables the Pluggable Authentication Module interface.  If set to
         yes this will enable PAM authentication using
         ChallengeResponseAuthentication and PasswordAuthentication in
         addition to PAM account and session module processing for all
         authentication types.
```

Note that this is still limited in authentication types; so if you authenticate via ssh keys then PAM isn't called for "auth" stack.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned, UsePam is set to true.
However, what you say concerns me, Is there no way make it work with keys?
If there is no way, perhaps you could tell me of another way to grant capabilities on a per user basis?

Comment: The `auth` stack should only be called for authentication processes.  Setting capabilities isn't authentication; it would seem to be better in `session`.  But I don't know if that module supports the session stack.

Comment: `pam_cap` only supports the authentication (`auth`) route. Unfortunately

Comment: There used to be a `UseLogin` option, which would force the use of the "login" program but that interferes with things like privilege separation and so has been deprecated (or even removed; not sure) in more recent versions.